# Issue with jquery scroll event in Firefox not being fluid enough

Tags: jquery, firefox, scroll

I have a div with content and overflow assigned giving it two scroll bars.

On the inside of that div is another one which needs to be anchored to the bottom at all times.

To achieve this, I put a listener on the scroll event to reposition the div at the bottom of the div:

```
obj.scroll(function(e) {
    var uiValue = obj.scrollTop();
    $("#calendar-grid-key").animate({ bottom: -1 * uiValue }, 0);
});
```

It works beautifully on nearly every browser bar Firefox 3 on PC.  It has a strange lag (see video: http://www.jamiewilson.co.nz/ScreenFlow.mov).

Someone suggested stopping the event drawing, calculating the difference and then drawing but I don't quite follow and can't find anything online that lets me stop the draw and then restart it.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Actually it doesn't work in Firefox Mac either. So a moz timing issue? - No takers?

Comment: jamie-wilson, does my solution works?

Comment: Heya, no not yet, but I am desperately plugging away to get it to work with your code. the complexity of the page might be stopping it.  i'll try and keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsbin.com/oqaso3) solution? It doesn't move at all.

The main points:

Style:

```
  #calendar-grid-key {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  }
```

And js:

```
function moveCalendar() {
  $("#calendar-grid-key").offset({top: $("#container").offset().top + $("#container").height() - $("#calendar-grid-key").height(), left: $("#container").offset().left });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  moveCalendar();

  $("#container").scroll(function(e) {
    moveCalendar()
  });

});
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered, because your answer is right, it just doesn't seem to work in my situation (mainly because of the number of divs on the page). Thanks heaps ehpc :)